# Extract Info AD Attribute from Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run a PS script on all AD groups within the domain. I want to select the info attribute within the AD properties as this includes additional information.

I am trying to use the below script, i am getting the correct results however the info attribute never appears to be outputted. Any ideas?

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter *  -Properties info,samAccountName, DistinguishedName,Description,info | Export- .\groups.Csv
```

TIA

Comment: WHen it comes to ADDS and PowerShell, use the Windows tool purpose-built to write PowerShell code for you to use as-is or tweak as needed. [Use AD Administrative Center to Create PowerShell Commands](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands)

Comment: the actual feild name in ADUC is Notes however within ADSI the attribute is info.

Comment: Philip, Did you find the Answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter *  | Select-Object SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, Description | Export-Csv -Path .\groups.Csv
```

Update

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties info,description | Select-Object SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, Description, Info | Export-Csv -Path .\groups.Csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The info attribute is never shown in the output because there is no parameter called info.  To view what parameters you are able to capture, run

```
get-adgroup -filter * -properties *|select -first 1|get-member
```

Or to see what those values look like for a typical group you could run this

```
get-adgroup -filter * -properties *|select -first 1|format-list *
```